# Auto Launch an application after inactivity ios

Tags: ios, angular, mdm

I am currently developing a web-app in a kiosk that allows safari app and the kiosk web-app to be accessible on kiosk ipad.

Currently i have a problem, whenever the user switch to safari app from my kiosk web-app to browse external site ( tried iframe but have X-frame-options from the 3rd party site that does not allow iframing)  and idle for 5 minutes, i want the ipad to auto switch back or launch the kiosk web-app again.

As i notice Apple store has the "Screensaver" app that auto launch when it is idle or booted up.

How can i do it with Apple MDM or programmatically in iOS?

Comment: You can't. Write a native app and use SFSafariViewController

Comment: i did it that way. thanks!